# postgres update text column value into integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a PostgreSQL data-table with following data

```
id    assignmentId    folderId    folderId_new
1     2274            5332
2     2274            5348
3     2274            5349
4     2274            5350
46    2277            5355
75    2275            5351
76    2275            5352
77    2275            5353
78    2275            5354
...
```

and columns datatype

```
id                serial
assignmentId      integer
folderId          text
folderId_new      integer
```

I want to save the values of folderId column to folderId_new column.
I have tried following queries

```
update framethreshold set folderId_new = CAST (folderId AS integer)

update framethreshold set folderId_new = folderId::int
```

but results in the error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "" SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: What errors were they showing?

Comment: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
SQL state: 22P02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can write this query

```
update framethreshold set folderId_new = NULLIF(folderId, '')::int
```

hope this will work ;)